# Examples from http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations

Tags: discussion

I've found a site about "spurious correlations", namely:
http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations
Questions about examples (1 example -> 1 question) from the site are on topic?

Comment: What kind of questions? Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @Tim, it depends of the example. Relevant (I think) discussion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263951/misunderstandings-of-spurious-correlation. Some correlations are obviously random noise (people who drowned... vs Nicholas Cage films); another correlations are a trivial consequence of the almost-linear time-dependence of both variables (science spending vs. suicides)... but in some (interesting) cases, the correlation can be the consequence of some no obvious common cause.

Comment: This doesn't sound like on-topic for our site. If you want to discuss "why" some things correlate with each other, then this is not about statistics, but the "things" themselves. It'd be on topic if you wanted to ask general questions on things as correlation, regression, spurious correlation etc.

Comment: @Tim, OK. Thanks.

Comment: My sampling -- apart from being dismayed by the spurious waviness of the curves, which looks like use of an MS Excel option all too often misapplied -- is that all the examples are variations on one single point, that correlations can arise because variables trend in the same way over time for quite different reasons. It's an important point in any introduction to statistics, but questions on yet more examples would seem likely to be duplicates of each other, unless some very specific content makes any a worthwhile different question.

Comment: @NickCox, "... unless some very specific content makes any a worthwhile different question.", as I expected. Thanks.